# Why does chrome convert open sans font to cursive?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, webfonts

Disclaimer: This is totally not a CSS problem, but likely a bug with my Google Chrome installation.

For a while, I've noticed sites using the style: `font-family: Open sans, sans-serif`, ends up illegible cuz the entire page is converted to cursive characters

[image: Mangled gibberish]

Whenever I comment out that line, I get the system default font i.e. I can read the site. This isn't always possible since some sites use preprocessors that declare the font many times on the minified stylesheet. But it's not a big deal cuz I simply open the same page on Opera and do what I want there. Until today, one of the sites I tried to access threw a js error on Opera that forced me to investigate this.

So far, I've deleted open sans from control-panel/fonts and restarted twice. It worked momentarily, but resumed again after I hibernated as usual and resumed. Meanwhile, no replacement for the deleted open sans font has been restored to the control panel folder. I suspected the font file was corrupted

I've also seen the ClearType text setting suggestion but I doubt this has anything to do with that. I saw one suggestion about enabling/disabling some chrome experimental setting but I can no longer locate it in the sea of links visited. Does any one have a clue where the issue could stem from?